# Maven archetype raise error on executing Groovy script

Tags: java, maven, groovy, maven-archetype, archetypes

I made a custom maven Archetype and based on the [Maven Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html), added the file *archetype-post-generate.groovy* to the *src/main/resources/META-INF* folder.
In this groovy script I want to connect to a database and take some actions according to the data.
The script is as follow:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

Sql.withInstance(
        'jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=db;',
        'sa',
        'pass',
        'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver') { sql ->
    List rows = sql.rows('SELECT top 5 id, description FROM Project')
    for(row in rows) {
        println row.getProperty("id")
        println row.getProperty("description")
        println "/*************\\"
    }
}
```

After installing the archetype when I generate a module with it, once the script is executed, the following error is raised:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class groovy.sql.Sql
 @ line 1, column 1.
   import groovy.sql.Sql
   ^

1 error
```

Is there any solution to resolve this problem?

Comment: You can use Grab to add groovy-sql library to classpath of your script. Otherwise you need to add a plug-in dependency for groovy-sql.

Comment: @emilles Thanks so much for your constructive guidance. It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @emilles's guidance and [Groovy documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html), we can add any library to the classpath of script using the `@Grab` annotation.
For example:

```
@Grab('org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-sql:2.4.16')
@Grab('com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:8.4.1.jre8')
```